# Separator between icon and text action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I need to display a separator between the logo and text on the action bar. Is it possible to set this via styles?
P.S: My minSdk is 14, so I use system Holo elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure you can achieve this with the `style`. Generally the `dividers` are made for the `MenuItem`. A simplest way to do it, it's to add manually your divider inside your icon app and keep the width unchanged.

Comment: Thanks, I did it. But I think, I can no longer ask questions :(